Make two slant divs touch on the inside with shape-outside and clip-path and wrap text
I have the following HTML and CSS


.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

.left,
.right {
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
}

.left {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 70% 100%, 0 100%);
  shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 70% 100%, 0 100%);
}

.right {
  background-color: #2196F3;
  shape-outside: polygon(30% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(30% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right">Lorem Ipsum asj sjas hhjks hskj hsjkas hkjas hakjsh skjh skj hsakj sakja shkjas hkjsa hskj hskjs hkjshakjsh sksah kjlash akjshskjasha kjsl</div>
</div>



It look great but I can't figure out how to make the inside edges touch instead of being separated by a middle white section.  This is what it generates right now

Additionally, I want the text to wrap inside the dive and not break out.  Thanks in advance for any help.

You’ve made both only 50% wide and then cut them. Can you describe what final result you want - what is to remain constant as the size changes, is it the angle or the proportion that is cut away?

note that flexbox will not work with shape-outside, you need to remove it and use float

If I understood you correctly, perhaps this example can help you:


.container {
  --skew: 300px; /* <= adjust as you need */
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.left,
.right {
  width: calc(50% + var(--skew) / 2);
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
}

.left {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, calc(100% - var(--skew)) 100%, 0 100%);
  left: 0px;
}

.right {
  background-color: #2196F3;
  clip-path: polygon(var(--skew) 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  right: 0;
}

.left:before {
  content: '';
  width: var(--skew);
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
  shape-outside: polygon(var(--skew) 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}

.right:before {
  content: '';
  width: var(--skew);
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, calc(100% - var(--skew)) 100%, 0 100%);
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    Lorem Ipsum asj sjas hhjks hskj hsjkas hkjas hakjsh skjh skj hsakj sakja shkjas hkjsa hskj hskjs hkjshakjsh sksah kjlash akjshskjasha kjsl Lorem Ipsum asj sjas hhjks hskj hsjkas hkjas hakjsh skjh skj hsakj sakja shkjas hkjsa hskj hskjs hkjshakjsh sksah
    kjlash akjshskjasha kjsl Lorem Ipsum asj sjas hhjks hskj hsjkas hkjas hakjsh skjh skj hsakj sakja shkjas hkjsa hskj hskjs hkjshakjsh sksah kjlash akjshskjasha kjsl Lorem Ipsum asj sjas hhjks hskj hsjkas hkjas hakjsh skjh skj hsakj sakja shkjas hkjsa
    hskj hskjs hkjshakjsh sksah kjlash akjshskjasha kjsl
  </div>
  <div class="right">Lorem Ipsum asj sjas hhjks hskj hsjkas hkjas hakjsh skjh skj hsakj sakja shkjas hkjsa hskj hskjs hkjshakjsh sksah kjlash akjshskjasha kjsl Lorem Ipsum asj sjas hhjks hskj hsjkas hkjas hakjsh skjh skj hsakj sakja shkjas hkjsa hskj hskjs hkjshakjsh sksah
    kjlash akjshskjasha kjsl Lorem Ipsum asj sjas hhjks hskj hsjkas hkjas hakjsh skjh skj hsakj sakja shkjas hkjsa hskj hskjs hkjshakjsh sksah kjlash akjshskjasha kjsl Lorem Ipsum asj sjas hhjks hskj hsjkas hkjas hakjsh skjh skj hsakj sakja shkjas hkjsa
    hskj hskjs hkjshakjsh sksah kjlash akjshskjasha kjsl</div>
</div>



In this example, I take into account that text can be in both blocks. By changing the CSS variable (--skew), you can adjust the skew you want.

Thanks, this is what i was looking for

Since the div's are already clipped, all it takes is to nudge them to the side, for example with a negative margin, in your case -15%.
This would make the combined width 85% of the container. To compensate I use an inner container wider by ~15%. This may effect the angel of the diagonals.


.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider {
  display: flex;
  width: calc(100% / 0.85);
}

.left,
.right {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
}

.left {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 70% 100%, 0 100%);
  shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 70% 100%, 0 100%);
}

.right {
  background-color: #2196F3;
  shape-outside: polygon(30% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(30% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  margin-left: -15%;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right">Lorem Ipsum asj sjas hhjks hskj hsjkas hkjas hakjsh skjh skj hsakj sakja shkjas hkjsa hskj hskjs hkjshakjsh sksah kjlash akjshskjasha kjsl</div>
  </div>
</div>



